# How to use tfdf.builder.CARTBuilder to build/train a decision tree by hand

Tags: python, tensorflow

## Expectation

Use the `tfdf.builder.CARTBuilder` to build a decision tree structure and train it with the literal dataset, and optimize the tree structure per the performance.

The process is like manually replicate the training process using `tfdf.keras.CartModel` but the benefit is that I can adjust the tree structure per needs, not only focusing on the model performance, which will be helpful if `intuitive rules` are needed.

## Sample code

I tried to use the `tfdf.builder.CARTBuilder` to build the structure and fit/predict but the results are not as expected as the fitting process does not lead to change of the prediction of leaves.

Below are some sample code with a sample dataset running in `Colab`

```py
import tensorflow_decision_forests as tfdf

import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import collections


# Download the dataset
!wget -q https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/palmer_penguins/penguins.csv -O /tmp/penguins.csv

# Load a dataset into a Pandas Dataframe.
dataset_df = pd.read_csv("/tmp/penguins.csv")

model_trial_idx = 10

# Create the model builder

model_trial_idx += 1
model_path = f"/tmp/manual_model/{model_trial_idx}"

builder = tfdf.builder.CARTBuilder(
    path=model_path,
    objective=tfdf.py_tree.objective.ClassificationObjective(
        label="species", classes=["Adelie", "Non-Adelie"]))


# Create some alias
Tree = tfdf.py_tree.tree.Tree
SimpleColumnSpec = tfdf.py_tree.dataspec.SimpleColumnSpec
ColumnType = tfdf.py_tree.dataspec.ColumnType
# Nodes
NonLeafNode = tfdf.py_tree.node.NonLeafNode
LeafNode = tfdf.py_tree.node.LeafNode
# Conditions
NumericalHigherThanCondition = tfdf.py_tree.condition.NumericalHigherThanCondition
CategoricalIsInCondition = tfdf.py_tree.condition.CategoricalIsInCondition
# Leaf values
ProbabilityValue = tfdf.py_tree.value.ProbabilityValue

builder.add_tree(
    Tree(
        NonLeafNode(
            condition=NumericalHigherThanCondition(
                feature=SimpleColumnSpec(name="bill_length_mm", type=ColumnType.NUMERICAL),
                threshold=40.0,
                missing_evaluation=False),
            
            pos_child=NonLeafNode(
                condition=CategoricalIsInCondition(
                    feature=SimpleColumnSpec(name="island",type=ColumnType.CATEGORICAL),
                    mask=["Dream", "Torgersen"],
                    missing_evaluation=False)
                ,pos_child=LeafNode(value=ProbabilityValue(probability=[0.8, 0.2], num_examples=10))
                ,neg_child=LeafNode(value=ProbabilityValue(probability=[0.1, 0.9], num_examples=20))
                ),
            
            neg_child=LeafNode(value=ProbabilityValue(probability=[0.2, 0.8], num_examples=30))
            )
        )
    
    )

builder.close()

manual_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

# Convert the pandas dataframe into a tf dataset.

dataset_df['species_binary'] = dataset_df['species'] == 'Adelie'

dataset_tf_2 = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(dataset_df[['bill_length_mm','island','species_binary']], label="species_binary")


# model compile and fit
manual_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
                       tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()])


manual_model.fit(dataset_tf_2)
```

## Questions

- The above code runs without error, but the tree does not reflect the fitting results, the prediction prob and number of samples stay the same, which is very weird, looks like the `manual_model` is a completely static model. How can we define the prob and number of samples before running the model on some data?

[image]

- I assume that the `tfdf.builder.CARTBuilder` is used to build a shell, and the performance of each node can be reflected after fitting/prediction. I am very confused why it requires me to define the value in the leaf in the first place and the value remains the same after fitting/prediction, did I miss anything?
- What is the best practice to use `tfdf.builder.CARTBuilder` to build a decision tree by hand on earth?

## Reference:

- Creating a model by hand: https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/tutorials/advanced_colab#creating_a_model_by_hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF-DF author here.

The discussion of this issue has been moved to the [TF-DF Github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/issues/184), so I'll just summarize some results.

1. TF-DF does not offer an automated way to update leaf probabilities and number of samples per leaf. It is possible to [implement an algorithm](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/issues/184#issuecomment-1609029926) that performs these computations and updates the graph, since TF-DF does expose the necessary primitives.
2. CARTBuilder is a tool for experts experiment with hand-crafted decision trees. It builds a full tree that can be used for inference, this includes the leaf probabilities.
3. The best practice is highly dependent on the use case, since the builder is a niche tool for experts. It is common to just use dummy values the leaf probabilities and the number of samples. This is reasonable if the tree is only used for inference and the probabilities it computes are irrelevant.

Comment: This [discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/issues/184) in the TFDF repo has the answer as @rstz suggested.